# How to use post cover image as Card Image for twitter

Tags: vue.js, gridsome, twitter-card, share-open-graph, vue-meta

I'm trying to use Gridsome [`metaInfo`](https://gridsome.org/docs/head/#add-head-meta-data-to-pages--templates) to create a [Twitter Card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/abouts-cards) with the *Cover Image* of the current post, but the image is not showing in the card.

```
<template>
  <Layout>
  ...
    <g-image ref="coverImage" alt="Cover image" v-if="$page.post.cover_image" :src="$page.post.cover_image" />
  ...
  </Layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  metaInfo () {
    return {
      title: this.$page.post.title,
      meta: [{
        property: 'og:image',
        content: this.$refs.coverImage? this.$refs.coverImage.src : (this.$page.meta.siteUrl + '/logo/LOGO.png')
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<page-query>
query Post ($id: ID!) {
  post: post (id: $id) {
    title
    path
    cover_image (width: 860, blur: 10)
  },
  meta: metadata {
    siteUrl
  },
}
</page-query>
```

Since the `g-image` know how to resolve the image path I have to use it in order to put the image path in the `meta` tags.

---

***Editors**- this question is for documenting my knowledge, I know the answer and I hope the question will be good by itself*

Answer (score 1):

To get the [*Twitter Card*](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/abouts-cards) working you need few steps.

### Get the real image path

You're right, when you querying the *GraphQL* for an image, you getting an object instead of image path. But to get the image path you just need to access to the `src` property in the object:

```js
metaInfo () {
  return {
    title: this.$page.post.title,
    meta: [{
      property: 'og:image',
      content: this.$page.post.cover_image?.src || '/logo/LOGO.png'
    }]
  }
}
```

### Get the right Image Size

> Images for this Card support an **aspect ratio of 2:1** with minimum dimensions of 300x157 or a maximum of 4096x4096 pixels
> *[Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image) (search for `twitter:image`)*

And over the internet, you can find the recommended size is **1200x630**, see the [Open Graph Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/) for example.

Of course, it is better to make sure you're using an image with the right dimensions, but even if your image is not feet, you can query it with the right dimensions by *GraphQL*, and it will crop your image if needed:

```
<page-query>
query Post ($id: ID!) {
  post: post (id: $id) {
    ...
    cover_image (width: 1200, height: 630)
  },
}
</page-query>
```

### Full Image Path

*Twitter* requires a **full path** to your image (*Facebook*, for example, accept path relative to the host), so you need to join the `siteUrl` to the image path:

```js
meta: [{
  name: 'twitter:image',
  content: this.$page.meta.siteUrl + (this.$page.post.cover_image?.src || '/logo/LOGO.png')
}]
```

### Misc and Testing

Of course, you need to define the other `meta` tags, and please note the *Twitter* tags should be with `name` and `content`, but the *Open Graph* tags should be with `property` and `content`:

```html
<!-- For Open Graph -->
<meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.png">

<!-- For Twitter -->
<meta name="twitter:image" content="path/to/image.png">
```

Then, validate your page with these tools, and see their warnings:

- [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)
- [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
- [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)

Also, you can use [Localhost Open Graph Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localhost-open-graph-chec/gcbnmkhkglonipggglncobhklaegphgn) extension to test your local website.